# Command Line Interface - Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I'm a bit confused about command line interface smartface on windows.How can i use it?

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/clitool/

Comment: I'm trying to install smartface command line interface on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the installation part:
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/clitool/#installation

Write this command to the terminal: npm install smartface -g
And continue with the steps in the guide above.